# Kafka Server Properties - unable to connect to broker

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-kafka

Lets say Kafka is running as a single node broker on an AWS EC2 instance. The instance has the internal private IP `10.0.0.1`. I want to connect to that broker directly from the same EC2 instance and from another EC2 instance in the same VPC and subnet. The security groups are allowing the connection. 
Which settings do I have to use to get the connection running?

I tried `listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092` and `advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092`. With that setting I can connect to the broker from local (the same instance where the broker is running), but I can't reach the broker from the second EC2 instance.

Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages that you could share?

Comment: I'm getting only timeout errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to connect to the Kafka instance inside of AWS from one EC2 instance to another the internal ip address should work.

The producer and consumers should make use of the internal private ip addresses as well for both the broker and zookeeper.

Additionally, you may need to verify that the IP Tables at the OS level aren't blocking the communication.